# Find lines that contains object.object.property in VS Studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio, search

I have something like this in my code:

```
cust.main.city
```

I need to find all such occurrences where it has atleast 2 dots I mean references.

So i tried this

```
[].+.[].+
```

but it also gave me :

```
cust.Res;
```

I only want those lines which has atleast 2 dots (`.`) in it so I can check further.

Request you to please guide me.

Comment: Try `\w+(?:\.\w+){2,}`

Comment: Great!!! It worked. Thanks a Lot Wiktor....Let me know how to mark your post as answer. !

Comment: But doesn't it match anything, even `var  s  = "1.1.1111";`? Probably you need a more sophisticated solution?

Comment: Ideally, yes. But this also helped me. So no issues !!! Thanks again!!! How to upvote your answer please let me know. I am not able to see any button to mark your post as answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53351981/3832970

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `[].+.[].+` regex is a misleading pattern. [It matches](https://regex101.com/r/wc6kd4/1)  a single char from a `[].+.[]` character class (that is, `]`, `.`, `+` and `[`) and then matches 1 or more chars other than newline chars (i.e. the rest of the line).

You may match those entities with

```
\w+(?:\.\w+){2,}
```

**Details**

- `\w+` - 1 or more [word chars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#word-character-w) (digits, letters, `_` and some other Unicode chars)
- `(?:` - start of a [non-capturing group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#noncapturing-groups) (see also [SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do)):

  - `\.`  - a literal dot char
  - `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `){2,}` - end of the group that will be [repeated 2 or more times](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions#match-at-least-n-times-n).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XBQYDB/1).

Comment: Accepted the answer ! However can't upvote due to less reputations as of now... :)

Comment: @Prashant Yes, you will only be able to do that once you reach 15 rep points.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried back slash escape for the period?

```
import re
pattern = r"^\w+\.\w+\.\w+$"
re.match(pattern, "cust.main.city")
```